# find command using ssh

Tags: shell

The below example shows the way how I need the file search and output type which works well in local find.

```
> find /DBBACKMEUP/ -not -name "localhost*" -type f -name "*2012-10-26*" -exec du -b {} \; | awk '{print $2 "\t" $1}' | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'

monitor_2012-10-26_22h00m.11.29.135.Friday.sql.gz   119601
test_2012-10-26_22h00m.10.135.Friday.sql.gz 530
status_2012-10-26_22h00m.1.29.135.Friday.sql.gz 944
```

But I need to print the same command on many servers. So I have planned to exec like this.

```
>ssh root@192.168.87.80 "find /DBBACKMEUP/ -not -name "localhost*" -type f -name "*2012-10-26*" -exec du -b {} \; | awk '{print $2 "\t" $1}' | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'"
```

Ofcourse this gives be a blank output. Any way to parse such a search string in shell and get the output that I desire by ssh?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your ssh command there has lots of quotes and double-quotes, which may be the root of your problem (no pun intended).  I'd recommend that you create a shell script that will run the find command you desire, them place a copy of it on each server.  After that, simply use ssh to execute that shell script instead of trying to pass in a complex command.

**Edit:** 
I think I misunderstood; please correct me if I'm wrong.  Are you looking for a way to create a loop that will run the command on a range of IP addresses?  If so, here's a recommendation - create a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((C=0; C<255; C++)) ; do
  for ((D=0; D<255; D++)) ; do
    IP="192.168.$C.$D"
    ssh root@$IP "find /DBBACKMEUP/ -not -name "localhost*" -type f -name "*2012-10-26*" -exec du -b {} \; | awk '{print "\$"2 \"\\t\" "\$"1}' | awk -F'/' '{print "\$"NF}'"
  done
done
```

Comment: Thats the exact thing I have done. But IPs would be different in my case as it takes data from different gateway. So I have sourced the ips calling the loop as a function.

Answer (score 0):

Each server?? That must be 749 servers - Your option goes good for hardworkers.. my approach goes good for lazy goose ;) Just a trial did the click ;)

```
ssh root@192.168.47.203 "find /DBBACKMEUP/ -not -name "localhost*" -type f -name "*2012-10-26*" -exec du -b {} \; | awk '{print "\$"2 \"\\t\" "\$"1}' | awk -F'/' '{print "\$"NF}'"

Tel_Avaya_Log_2012-10-26_22h00m.105.23.Friday.sql.gz    2119
test_2012-10-26_22h00m.10.25.Friday.sql.gz  529
OBD_2012-10-26_22h00m.103.2.203.Friday.sql.gz   914
```